# R creating a new variable by matching a variable in two datasets

Tags: r

I have one variable I am trying to pare down to a more manageable length of values. I exported a list of the variable's unique values into a csv file, and assigned them more general names in an adjacent column. E.g.,

```
EVTYPE  new_category

- x1    x
- x2    x
- x3    x
- x4    x
- y1    y
- y2    y
- y3    y
```

I then uploaded this back into R, and am trying to create a new variable, where if old_val = x1, new_var2 =x , and so on. There are about 1,000 unique values in the old_val variable, so nesting ifelse statements or something similar isnt really possible.  Here is some code I am working on, but cannot get to work yet, where dataset = the overall dataset and new_data = the dataset with the unique values: (Sorry for the poor formatting, not sure how to do that correctly for the above list)

```
ND_row_count <- NROW(new_data)
for (i in 1:ND_row_count){
  if (dataset$EVTYPE==new_data$EVTYPE2[i]) {
    dataset$new_category <- new_data$new_category[i]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the vectorised function, `match`, for this.

The following should return (and assign to `dataset$new_category`) a vector of new categories corresponding to your long vector of original values.

```
dataset$new_category <- new_data$new_category[match(dataset$EVTYPE, new_data$EVTYPE2)]
```

Above, `match` finds, for each element of `dataset$EVTYPE` the position of the matching element of `new_data$EVTYPE2`. We then use that vector of indices to subset `new_data$new_category`.